# JavaScript with rails partial

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a website and I'm having a very strange bug that I can't seem to figure out. I have a table and in each row the the table there is a column with a button. When the button is clicked a tooltip is supposed to pop up. This table it rendered from a partial. Now the issue that I'm having is that the tool tip is not popping up for the icons in the table unless there is an extra icon on the webpage that's not in the table. So here is the code where I render the partial (this won't show the tooltip on the table):

```
<div id="mainPage">
  ...
  <section class="fluid">
    <%= render "all_page_graphs" %>
  </section>
  ...
</div>
```

Here is the code for the partial:

```
<i class="filter-icon os blue" data-filter-name="GFilter">
  <div class="tooltip-container">
    <div class="tooltip-tail top"></div>
    <div class="tooltip top clearfix center">
     None
    </div>
  </div>
</i>
```

If I render my table like this:

```
<div id="mainPage">
  ...
  <section class="fluid">
    <%= render "all_page_graphs" %>
  </section>
  ...
</div>
<i class="filter-icon os blue" data-filter-name="GFilter">
```

the tooltip shows up when you click the button in the table.

I think I've isolated the issue to be in the javascript. When I get the tooltip working in the chart I hit this line of code:

```
function FilterTooltips(){
  "use strict";

  if ($(".filter-icon").length == 0)
    return;

  var openFilter = false;
  var $lastFilterOpen = null;

  //hit this function when the tool tip works,
  //but I don't hit it when the tool tip won't
  //load.
  $('body').click(function(e) {
    //do stuff
  }];
```

I think the issue has to do with the `$('body')` and the fact that the tooltip is loading is supposed to show up in a table thats being rendered from a partial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `$(document.body).click` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Delegation**

Although I don't have a direct answer to your question, I think the issue *may* be to do with [Javascript delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate):

```
$(document).on("click", ".tooltip-tail top", function(){
    ...
});
```

I know you've got this set up already - I would refine it to use the above code. The difference being if you use the code above, it essentially allows you to bind the "click" event to the particular element *through* the document / body

You must remember that Javascript works with the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - meaning it cannot tell *how* the page has been rendered, only that it has certain elements. Further, these elements need to be present at `load` - if you don't have the elements present at this time, JS won't be able to bind to them

Hopefully this gives you some more overview - I am sorry I cannot help further!